# Jquery maphilight issue with IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-9

[maphilight](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/) work fine on firefox, IE7/8 but it not working on IE9. Live [demo](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html) also not working with IE9. Are there any fixes?

Comment: The demo works correctly for me in IE9. (Except for one minor render error of an extra line across some of the map.) Perhaps the plugin author has since fixed it? If you are still having problems, what are the exact issues you are having? Any error messages? Screenshots of what works and what doesn't? Expected behavior you're not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

SVG requires [excanvas plugin](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/06/03/google_svg_internet_explorer/) to work on Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also delete the line 192 of the plugin.